# Web hosting inventory listing

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver

I need an efficient way to manage our massive inventory of clients and domain names. We must be able to organize where the domain is registered, what are the nameservers, which mail service it uses (MX, if any), where is the website, etc.  Each element or party can have a client contact as well as a technical one associated with it.

Furthermore, it would simplify maintenance if we had the possibility to automatically query DNS and whois databases to refresh the information on demand, or also have a list of servers (IPs) and accounts we are managing so it can be cross-referenced to clearly see what is our responsibility and not.

We do not need CRM or billing functionalities.

Right now, the solutions are either :

- manually maintained spreadsheets (current solution, innefficient and prone to error),
- a custom interface backed by a custom relational database (costly development time).

With all the hosting and web agencies in the world there must already be a better solution available.

What other solutions am I not thinking about ? Is there a better way to accomplish this task ?

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad and will primarily result in [recommendations for resources](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

There are a large number of domain management systems out there.  [Here is a list](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1147398) at the Web Hosting talk forum.

I use WHMCS which is one of the most popular.  It works well and will do what you want.

It has a billing section, but you don't have to use that.